# When integrating a new cat into a house with a resident cat, how should I divide my time?

Tags: cats, multi-pet-families, introducing-pets

I have a newly adopted cat (female, spayed, 1.5 yrs) in a safe room.

I have a resident cat (female, spayed, 3 yrs) in the rest of the house.

I am not yet at the point where the new cat is ready to roam the house or where the cats are ready to meet.

How should I divide my time? I work from home so can be anywhere during the day, and both areas have beds so I can sleep anywhere at night.

My resident cat is very attached to me and gets noticeably jealous (usually expressed as misdirected aggression when I am near or come out of the safe room) / depressed when I'm not around, she also has some serious separation anxiety issues, although I've been making progress in that regard in the past year. I want to both bond with the new cat but not make the old cat resent the new one before they even meet, and also I want to make sure the new cat has time to just relax in the safe room without me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best if you sleep on the side which has your resident cat more often, and sleep in the new cat's room once or twice for the first week. In the morning spend the time you used to spend with your resident cat like usual (except if it was all the time), then spend a lot of time with the new cat (except if she's really shy to ever come near you, in that case it needs more time to be alone).

Make sure the new cat is satisfied with the time you spend with her, and is happy and ready to let you go for a while. If you do that, your resident cat will miss you and will come to you when you are back. Here you should allow her to give you love and you should show her that you missed her like never before by giving her lots of attention, treats, and play. Be aware that you won't need to do this always, just for the first few days or so.

After that, both cats should be used to the fact that you won't be with them 99% of the time, and they should be okay with it. Just show them both love and affection, possibly give the resident cat more. If you give the new cat a lot of love and nice stuff, it wouldn't ever be ready to let you go and may start calling you once you leave the room.

But that's for you to decide. The resident cat shouldn't feel abondond and the new cat should feel at home but both should be okay with you leaving for some time. Leave them both toys and puzzles, catnip stuffed toys are also a good idea, water and a little food out for them to spend their time on.